# How can I reset my IP address and stay on the same page?

Tags: anonymity, session

Whenever I hit "New Identity" it knocks me out of my session, is there a way to just simply have it reload?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do, I mean specifically which website or what kind of application, I am trying to find if you are using Ajax

Comment: I think that this is a new feature of the Tor Browser. You would have to install Tor and Vidalia manually, then access the Vidalia 'New Identity' function independently from the browser you will have configured to use Tor as a socks proxy.